# Visualizing a teachable machine model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-visualization

I am using a teachable machine to do my wake word recognition, which runs in electron. Now the model works fine, but I want to visualize it. I have seen tutorials on how to visualize TensorFlow ,Keras models etc.. But what to do for a teachable machine model.

Comment: Are you referring to https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/ ?

Comment: Also you should add some code/info/etc. e.g. model architecture.

Comment: yes , i am referring to https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/

Comment: actually i found an app that does exactly what i want. the app name is NETRON .